# hard disk problem, interpretation of smartctl output

Tags: hard-drive

I need help with the interpretation of the smartctl output. I did the smartctl check because this week after a loss of power my ubuntu system first showed some errors while booting infsck and then end up with a blue screen. The output of smartctl is:

```
=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                                        was completed without error.
                                        Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                                        without error or no self-test has ever 
                                        been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:                (  139) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:                    (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                                        Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                                        Suspend Offline collection upon new
                                        command.
                                        Offline surface scan supported.
                                        Self-test supported.
                                        Conveyance Self-test supported.
                                        Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                                        power-saving mode.
                                        Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                                        General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:        (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (  99) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:        (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:              (0x1081) SCT Status supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED   WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   114   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       59491560
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   099   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1921
5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       6246697
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2405
10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1319
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   099   099   099    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 1
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       4
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   060   054   045    Old_age   Always       -       40 (Min/Max 26/46)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       128
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4619
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   040   046   000    Old_age   Always       -       40 (0 16 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 1
CR = Command Register [HEX]
FR = Features Register [HEX]
SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
ER = Error register [HEX]
ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2383 hours (99 days + 7 hours)
When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

After command completion occurred, registers were:
ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
-- -- -- -- -- -- --
40 51 00 d8 fd 07 00  Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0007fdd8 = 523736

Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
-- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
60 00 00 88 fe 07 40 00      00:00:18.576  READ FPDMA QUEUED
60 00 00 88 fd 07 40 00      00:00:18.575  READ FPDMA QUEUED
60 00 00 88 fc 07 40 00      00:00:18.574  READ FPDMA QUEUED
60 00 00 88 fb 07 40 00      00:00:18.571  READ FPDMA QUEUED
60 00 00 88 fa 07 40 00      00:00:18.569  READ FPDMA QUEUED

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2405         -
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%      2403         -
# 3  Extended offline    Completed without error       00%      2403         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
 1        0        0  Not_testing
 2        0        0  Not_testing
 3        0        0  Not_testing
 4        0        0  Not_testing
 5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Answer (score 0):

The lines that I would care about are:

```
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED  

ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED   WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE  
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   114   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       59491560
```

That seems like a large value.

```
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   020    Old_age   Always       -       1921
```

Power up and down much?

```
7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   067   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       6246697
```

Again, seems large.

```
9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2405
```

Use 2405 when looking at the ATA error below.

```
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   099   099   099    Old_age   Always   FAILING_NOW 1
```

That is scary, yes?

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1  
ATA Error Count: 1  

Error 1 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 2383 hours (99 days + 7 hours)
```

2405-2383 = 22 hours since ATA Error 1

```
Error: UNC at LBA = 0x0007fdd8 = 523736
```

It tried to read disk block 523736, and got the UNC error.

Suggestion: (YMMV, Not responsible, ...) boot from a Live USB/CD and run `fsck` again.

Start planning a disk replacement, ensure you have a current backup that you can restore. Pending the `fsck`s, I would be concerned.

Comment: In addition to the smartctl I ran "sudo badblocks -nvs /dev/sda" last night. I stopped this morning at about 50% progress of the test. Until then no errors were found. Anyway maybe it would be a good idea to buy a new hdd.

Comment: You should ignore RAW_VALUE unless you know for sure what that means. For example, some manufacturers set `Raw_Read_Error_Rate` to integer with lowest 32 bit counting the total events and high 16 bits counting the number of errors (for total of 48 bit integer). If this is true for the example drive, it has executed total of `59491560` read commands and seen `0` errors during those commands.